# Python module for shell commands

Tags: python, bash

I've got a bash script that's starting to cross that grey area where it should probably be rewritten in a scripting language.  Since I'm constantly tweaking the script bash is perfect because of how concise things are.  Mostly I'm manipulating output from one program to put into another program (i.e. using cat, grep, sed, tail, head).  I'm familiar with Python so I'm looking for a module that can essentially perform these commands.  I've found some stuff that uses subprocess to call bash commands but I don't want a wrapper for bash commands.  I also realize I could simply take the time to write most of these commands in python and even chain them fairly easily if I encapsulated them all into one class.  It seems like such an obvious thing though I find it hard to believe these utilities don't exist in a module that already exists.

Comment: If what you want to do is essentially run bash commands, you're better off continue using shell script.

Comment: Conversely, you are better off learning how to do things in Python rather than forking a new process to run simple programs.

Comment: Things like `subprocess` are good for running "heavyweight" programs (`vim`, a graphic editor, games, etc.) whose functionality would be nontrivial at best to reimplement in Python.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, `shutil` module in the standard library could be useful.  However, I don't recommend that you try to translate line-by-line from bash to python.  Instead you should go back to the original specification of the script and write it in python.  What's that?  No specification?  OK, then write one, make it abstract and language neutral.  Don't be side-tracked by your shell script.  Once you have done a few like this it will become 2nd nature and you won't want to look at bash again.

Comment: You ask why such a module does not exist.  I once tried to write a Shell-to-Perl (sorry, it was a long time ago) utility.  But it was Garbage-In/Garbage-out.  I found that most shell scripts that needed conversion were so badly written that they generated terrible Perl.  One reason why Python (and Perl) scripts tend to be faster is that people take more care over writing them (only *one* reason).  I gave up the conversion project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `os` module in python to have a command executed exactly as it would be in a command shell.

For example, if you have a file named "junk.txt" and want to use the "head" command on it, you would write `head junk.txt` in your shell.

In Python, it's

```
import os
os.system("head junk.txt")
```

Comment: `os.system()` is deprecated and replaced by the `subprocess` module.  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/